# Linux Libertine does not show Cyrillic small caps (XeLaTeX)

Tags: xetex, fontspec, ubuntu, small-caps, libertine

I'm trying to output any non-latin (in this particular case Cyrillic) small caps with XeLaTex using the following source code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
    SmallCapsFont={Linux Libertine O},
    SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps}]{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{document}
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

\textsc{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}

абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя

\textsc{абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя}

\end{document}
```

But I get the following output:

[image: PDF output]

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04.1.

```
$ xetex -version
XeTeX 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3-2014012222 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.1.1
Copyright 2013 SIL International and Jonathan Kew.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the XeTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the XeTeX source.
Primary author of XeTeX: Jonathan Kew.
Compiled with ICU version 52.1; using 52.1
Compiled with zlib version 1.2.8; using 1.2.8
Compiled with FreeType2 version 2.5.2; using 2.5.2
Compiled with Graphite2 version 1.2.4; using 1.2.4
Compiled with HarfBuzz version 0.9.25; using 0.9.27
Compiled with fontconfig version 2.11.0; using 2.11.0
Compiled with libpng version 1.2.49; using 1.2.50
Compiled with poppler version 0.24.5

$ apt-cache show fonts-linuxlibertine | grep '^Version'
Version: 5.3.0-2
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There are no small caps Cyrillic letters in Linux Libertine, as far as I know. Some software can *fake* small caps, so it's possible that a font viewing program displays them even if the font doesn't have the real thing.

Comment: Thanks @egreg! Yes, indeed, I've just checked in FontForge, the current version of Linux Libertine font has only latin small-caps glyphs.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the characters are only faked by the font viewer applications and doesn't exist in the font